# How to get ant to not print the BuildException/ExitStatusException stack trace

Tags: java, ant

I have written an ant task (bnd) that needs to indicate failure. The only way to indicate failure that I found is to throw a `BuildException`/`ExitStatusException`. However, I do not want a stack trace because it just takes up unnecessary screen space. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I would have been proud to answer to one of the people involved in the conception of the OSGi technology I am using every day but unfortunately I don't have this answer ;-) (my first though is that this is not possible with ant, at least without dirty hack)

Comment: Are you running ant with the `-v` flag? Without it, a BuildException should not cause a stack trace to the console. With `-v` it does. That's how ant is supposed to work.

Comment: Hmm, when I add -v it prints a lot more trace info so -v is not on there ... If I run a <fail/> task, I not get the trace but when my code throws the BuildException it does ...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the tutorial at http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html#complex

There they show an example that just fails gracefully, throwing a BuildException in the custom task but not showing the stack trace in the console window.

The code to pay attention to is in the `execute()` method of the '`HelloWorld`' Class, and where the `helloworld` task is called from the `use.fail` target.